# How to use multiple versions of dompdf at the same time?

Tags: php, dompdf

I am currently able to render documents in an old version of dompdf and in version 6.0 if I do them as separate script executions. I would like to be able to render some documents in the old version and some in the new version at the same time. I tried using namespaces like this, and I required this file:

```
<?php
namespace domold {
    require_once('dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');
}
namespace domnew {
    require_once('dompdf6.0/dompdf_config.inc.php');
}
?>
```

Then I try to create an instance of each corresponding class like this

```
$dompdf = new domold\DOMPDF();
//rest of code here

$dompdf = new domnew\DOMPDF();
//rest of code here
```

and I get errors like Failed opening required 'd:\Apache2\htdocs\dompdf\include/domold\dompdf.cls.php'

Is there a better way to do this? I need to use both versions, so please don't tell me to use one version. Am I using namespaces incorrectly?

Thank you

Comment: It's still early in development, but there is a namespaced version of dompdf over at github: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/tree/develop

Comment: Also, why? If you really need to do this your best bet is to create an external PHP script that renders using the version you want. That way you don't run into any namespace/class conflicts. I do something similar here: http://eclecticgeek.com/dompdf/debug.php

Comment: Hello, I will read into both of these. As for why, it is partially due to laziness. I currently have hundreds of php/html documents that are rendered "on the fly" and I made them a long time ago when dompdf was fairly new. I had to do strange things to get the forms to render exactly how I needed them and they do not render correctly in the new version of dompdf. I want to use the new version of dompdf for new forms going forward, so I would like to render old and new together with the different versions and slowly cycle out all the old forms.

Comment: As for the external php script, do you mean make a renderer and call it with exec() or something?  Thanks buddy.

Comment: I totally understand. If it ain't broke, right? I meant to specifically call out using `exec()` as that's how I'm doing it. I can't really think of any other way, unless you want to give the in-development, untested, namespaced version a try.